# Program to ask for 'I agree' or 'I disagree' to T&Cs

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-7

I am looking for a program that asks a user to accept some Terms & Condition's **post-login**.

I know I can use the `legalnoticecaption` and `legalnoticetext` but that is **pre-login**, and I want the program to ask the user after login. Also, these 2 registry entries do not allow someone to deny them, they can only click 'OK'.

Requirements:

- Free
- Asks for acceptance post-login (because I don't want to mess with any system files, which I would if I had it pre-login)
- Logs which user agrees and denies
- Logs user off (and displays message) if the user clicks 'I disagree'
- Runs on Windows 7 (64 bit)
- Be a maximised program that is relatively hard to close without accepting or denying (i.e. no icon on taskbar, no close button etc.) but if there is a way to make the program absolutely unclosable, for example if the program could disable the keyboard when opened, then that would be great!

Bonuses (not necessary!):

- Allow to put my own logo on the screen that asks this
- Allow me to choose whether it says 'I Agree' and 'I do not agree' (or similar) or something else

Comment: A program can't make itself unclosable. By default, a user can open Task Manager (Ctrl-Alt-Del, Start Task Manager or Ctrl-Shift-Esc) and kill anything running in their session by default. You'll have to use external means (such as using Group Policy to disable Task Manager) to prevent that.

Comment: Why do you want to do this post log in?

Comment: @Oxinabox Because if I do i pre-login, I would need to edit system files (as a different program will need to give this functionality). I cannot use the legalnoticecaption and text because they only require the user to say OK, not no or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You'll essentially want to create a kiosk-mode installation of Windows 7.  With NOTHING enabled except your message, until after you approve accept it, at which time, kiosk mode is lifted.

Here are several links that should get you going:

- https://superuser.com/questions/614190/locking-down-a-windows-7-pc-to-just-a-browser
- http://download.cnet.com/Netkiosk-Standard/3000-18510_4-10874983.html
- http://www.kioware.com/
- http://www.sitekiosk.com/SiteKiosk/Default.aspx
- also try http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Launchers-Shutdown-Tools/Auto-Logon-Lock.shtml
- also from another StackExchange question here:  https://superuser.com/questions/352616/windows-7-automatically-login-and-lock, **try this:**

> **AUTO LOGON AND LOCK**:   http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Launchers-Shutdown-Tools/Auto-Logon-Lock.shtml
>
> ***Auto Logon to Windows and immediately Lock Workstation (Safe Mode
> protected too)***
>
> Auto Logon & Lock is a small utility that enables your Windows PC to
> automatically logon to a user account on boot and then lock the
> desktop so a password is still required. Some of the reasons you might
> want to do this are: Faster boot time. The additional post-logon start
> up items are also started after Windows boots. Which means when you
> press the power button on your PC and come back after a few minutes,
> its completely booted up. No need to wait for additional software to
> load after you logon. Automatically resume downloads etc. when your PC
> reboots due to a power failure or crash. On XP you could do this by
> installing the application as a system service. In Vista and 7,
> Session 0 Isolation makes using a system service a pain, not to
> mention it's insecure. Just put your applications in the regular
> Windows Start Up folder and they will be launched after the auto
> logon. It password protects Safe Mode as well. Existing auto logon
> methods leave Safe Mode unprotected. It locks the desktop before
> Explorer is started. Other methods auto-lock using an autorun/start up
> entry which leave the PC logged on and unlocked until the autorun
> entries are executed (which can even take several minutes).

.

#### Question though:  could you further explain your comment above:

> "@Oxinabox Because if I do i pre-login, I would need to edit system
> files (as a different program will need to give this functionality). I
> cannot use the legalnoticecaption and text because they only require
> the user to say OK, not no or anything else. –  shub May 24 at 10:12"

I don't really understand why you have to ***"mess with system files."***

Comment: I will have to mess with system files if I install a 3rd party program to do *anything* before login - because Windows has no option, itself, to ask a user to click yes or no. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: These kiosk programs look great but I don't know how to display a message. PLease tell me if I'm missing anything